# Iterate through the tokens of a list not known in advance (\@for + \csname)

Tags: latex-base

If I want to iterate through the tokens of `\myList` I can simply do

```latex
\def\myList{one,two,three}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iterateThroughMyList}{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \@for\next:=\myList\do{%
        \if@tempswa//\else\@tempswatrue\fi\next%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\iterateThroughMyList
```

which correctly prints:

one//two//three

But what should I do if I wanted to iterate through the tokens of *any* list not known in advance?

If I try the following code,

```latex
\def\myList{one,two,three}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iterateThroughSomeList}[1]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \@for\next:=\csname #1\endcsname\do{%
        \if@tempswa//\else\@tempswatrue\fi\next%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\iterateThroughSomeList{myList}
```

what gets printed is:

one,two,three

(which means that no iteration happens, since the comma is left untouched)

I guess there must be some combination of `\expandafter` missing, but I do not know which combination is the right one.

Comment: "tokens" has a technical meaning here and `one,two,three` is a list of 13 tokens. (as you would find using a token loop such as `\@tfor`)  I think (since you mention `\@for`) you want to treat this as a three item comma list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. Got it.

Comment: For lists with separators, I would use the `listofitems` package.  If you literally mean "tokens", one-by-one, the `tokcycle` package could help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the csname first although it would be *much* simpler to use an `expl3` `clist` here, `expl3` has a pre-built data type `clist` for comma lists, existing functions to iterate over the items or (as here) insert tokes between items, and a genric mechanism for gerating a `c` variant function that takes a command by name rather tha as a command token.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\myList{one,two,three}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iterateThroughSomeList}[1]{%
    \@tempswafalse
    \expandafter\@for
    \expandafter\next
    \expandafter:%
    \expandafter=%
    \csname #1\endcsname\do{%
        \if@tempswa//\else\@tempswatrue\fi\next%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\iterateThroughSomeList{myList}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N\l_my_list
\clist_set:Nn\l_my_list{one,two,three}

\clist_use:Nn\l_my_list{//}% by command token

\par

\clist_use:cn{l_my_list}{//}% by name

\ExplSyntaxOn

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, David! It works. But what the sense of the three `\expandafter`? If I replace all the occurrence of `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter` with one single `\expandafter` it works too…

Comment: @madmurphy ah actually 1 is enough I forgot `\@for\next:=\myList` works (ie it expands once, I was expanding so making `\@for\next:=one,two,three\do`

Comment: Ok, perfect, thank you. If you correct your answer I will accept it as the “solving” one.

Comment: @madmurphy done